# "Can not find variable: X" error while using fetch from a URL

Tags: javascript, react-native

In React native, I would like to retrieve the js data from the web URL and use it. Here is my code:

```
export default class Test extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.subscription = 0;
        this.state = {
        };
        changePage = props.cb;
        console.log("props", props);


      render(){

        return (
            <Container  ref="park-places-ref">

                <View style={styles.viewmain}>

                <View style={styles.viewborder}>

                </View>

          fetch('https://online.ssm.it/php/mobile/parkinfo') // Call the fetch function passing the url of the API as a parameter
          .then((response) => response.json()) // Transform the data into json
            data={response.body}
          })
            .catch(function() {
                // This is where you run code if the server returns any errors
            });

                <FlatList
                ItemSeparatorComponent={ () => <View style={ styles.rowSep } /> }

                Mydata={data}


                renderItem={

                    ({item}) => (
                    <View style={styles.row}>
                        <View style={styles.circle}   backgroundColor= {item.color}/>
                        <View style={styles.column}>
                            <Text style={styles.itemBold}>{item.extensioname}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.itemNormal}>{item.free}</Text>

                            <Text style={styles.itemBold}>{item.freeplaces}</Text>


                        </View>
                    </View>
                    )
                }
                keyExtractor={item => item.extensioname}
                />
                </View>


            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

}

Whenever I tried to retrieve the body of the data, I couldn't retrieve it and it shows me an error that:
I need to use the data in table as below:

> Can not find variable: response

Can you help me to solve the problem? Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) which shows the actual problem. Right now this is just a syntax error...

Comment: data={response}}) might have to do something with it.

Comment: @Andreas: I will update it now...

Comment: @Andreas: I have added it, is it sufficient?

Comment: The `fetch(...).then((response) => response.json()) data={response.body} .catch(function() { ... });` is still invalid (syntax error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need one more chain on your fetch() function call.

```
fetch( ... )
.then((response)=>response.json())
.then((resp)=> data={resp})
.catch( ... );
```

Check out the docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html

Comment: well i don't see anywhere you're using the data variable in your code. if you do get a response from the fetch call resp will exist